# How can I get the coordinates from Well Known Text to Coordinates in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, polygon

I am getting a polygon namely:

```
POLYGON ((62.774819280952215 -34.70286937581841, 55.90322656463832 2.5109802198130637, 144.0961880227551 45.901241006329656, -74.58619913225994 79.6020824520383, -74.58619913225994 -34.70286937581841, 62.774819280952215 -34.70286937581841))
```

But it gets converted to Well known text namely:

```
0103000020E61000000100000005000000B9B94269B9033C400E6ABFB513C33BC0B9B94269B9033C409B012EC896C33BC04651B17B3C043C409B012EC896C33BC04651B17B3C043C400E6ABFB513C33BC0B9B94269B9033C400E6ABFB513C33BC0
```

How do I get that Well known text to coordinates again? Please thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I got the answer, I think it might be best if you select it ST_AsGeoJSON(polygon) from the db.